# how to properly use PCL's ShadowPoints class

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

I'm using Point cloud library (PCL), and trying to remove shadow points from a point cloud.

in order to do so, I use ShadowPoints filter class. 
for some reason, it filters out all the points from my point cloud,
regardless to the threshold which I am using (in the attached code, I'm using the default threshold, but I tried to run this code with various threshold values).

I searched for relevant data online, but couldn't find the answer for my question. what am I missing here?

```
//input point cloud.
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr sourceCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr sourceCloudBasic(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

/* code for filling sourceCloud and sourceCloudBasic*/
...

//output point cloud 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr outCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>());
//filter object
pcl::ShadowPoints<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal> shadowfilters(true);
//sets the source point cloud
shadowfilters.setInputCloud(sourceCloud);

//calculates normals
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
ne.setInputCloud(sourceCloudBasic);
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>());
ne.setSearchMethod(tree);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
double normalsThreshold = 0.3;
ne.setRadiusSearch(normalsThreshold);
ne.compute(*cloud_normals);

//sets normals into shadowfilters
shadowfilters.setNormals(cloud_normals);

//sets threshold
double shadowThreshold = 0.1;
shadowfilters.setThreshold(shadowThreshold);

//filters
shadowfilters.filter(*outCloud);
```

much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.
the mesh was created from a noisy depth image - therefore the normals were inaccurate as well. It made the shadow filter to mark everything as shadow.
enlarging the radius search for the normal calculation improved the normals map and thus enabled the shadow filter to work properly.